# TypeToken of void or null

Tags: java, json, spring, gson

I can get `com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken`  of any class type like `String`

```
    Type responseType = new TypeToken<String>() {
    }.getType();
```

Is there is any way to get `TypeToken` of `void`  or `null`  ?

Comment: You can try [Void](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Void.html) class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exist a placeholder class to "represent" a [Void](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Void.html). So your code will look like:

```
  Type responseType = new TypeToken<Void>() {
    }.getType();
```